# Only first entry in list enters mysql table PHP even though trim is used

Tags: php, mysql, list, space, enter

I have this page of html

```
    <html>
<body>

<form action="new_group.php" method="post">

<div>
<label for="group_name">Group Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="group_name" id="group_name" />
</div>

<div>
<label for="invites">Invite...</label>
<input type="text" name="invites" id="invites" />
</div>

<div>
<label for="description">Description: </label>
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Which then has this PHP:

```
<?php
include "function_inc.php";
if(isset($_POST['group_name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['invites'])){
    $invites = explode(',', $_POST['invites']);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //avoids issues with quotations (either invalid quotation for referring to PHP variable or repeated double quotes)
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id'");
    foreach($result as $resul){
        foreach($resul as $resu){
            $logged_in_username = $resu;
        }}
    if(in_array($logged_in_username, $invites)){
    }else{
        $invites[] = $logged_in_username;
    }

    foreach($invites as $invite) {
        $invite = trim($invite);
        echo $invite . '<br />';
        $idres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$invite'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($idres) == 0) {
            exit("1 or more of the users that you entered do(es) not exist!");
        }
    }
    create_group($_POST['group_name'], $_POST['description'], $invites);
}
?>
```

and this is the create_group function:

```
function create_group($name, $description, $invites){
    global $link;
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $description);
    $names = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_name` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_name` = '$name'");
    $descriptions = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_description` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_description` = '$description'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($names) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($descriptions) == 0) {
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `groups` (`group_name`, `group_description`) VALUES ('$name', '$description')");
    } else {
        echo 'Group with that name/description already exists.';
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `group_id` FROM `groups` WHERE `group_name` = '$name'");

    foreach($result as $resul) {
        foreach($resul as $resu) {
            $group_id = $resu;
        }
    }
    foreach($invites as $invite) {
        $idres = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$invite'");
        foreach($idres as $idarr) {
            foreach($idarr as $id) {
                mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `group_members` (`group_id`, `user_id`, `confirmed?`) VALUES ('$group_id', '$id', 0)");
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'Group created!';
}
```

What I am confused about is the following: if I create a group (for testing purposes) and include my (the current user logged on's) name, and have commas but no spaces in between, everything works fine.   However, if I do the exact same thing, however I have spaces, only the first name in the array enters `group_members`.  As you can see, there is a trim statement.

I have no idea why this is.  Any help would be much appreciated as I am a beginner at PHP.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. enjoy having your server pwn3d...

Comment: @Marc B Sorry to be a n00b.  I know what SQL injection is, but where exactly are these vulnerabilities

Comment: read the site I linked to. it'll explain everything.

Comment: @MarcB I've looked at the site but, to be honest, I still don't understand what's wrong with my code (where the vulnerabilities are)

Comment: Then I suggest you stop working on this code until you DO learn where the problems are. You're writing web-based PHP code, which means you need to know defensive+secure programming practices from the get-go. Learning it after the fact is pointless - you're leaving yourself open for attack the whole time.

Comment: You're trimming in the `foreach` loop, but that just trims the copy in the variable `$invite`. It has no effect on the contents of the `$invites` array.

Comment: @MarcB I am now going to learn how to write secure sql code.  I am still only a beginner (14 year old) so I have plenty of time...

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for alerting me to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code:

```
foreach ($invites as $invite) {
    $invite = trim($invite);
    ...
}
```

The variable `$invite` is separate from the array element. Assigning to that variable does not modify the contents of the array. You can fix this by using a reference:

```
foreach ($invites as &$invite) {
    $invite = trim($invite);
    ...
}
```

The `&` prefix makes `$invite` a reference variable, i.e. an alias for the array element. Now, assigning to the variable updates the array element that it refers to.

Comment: Thank you for helping me once again!